# useTranslation not working with useEffect: rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a piece of code that should load a data from Back4App Platform and then show the results in my return.

I am using useTranslation and useEffect, and I get this error and crash:

> rendered more hooks than during the previous render

this is my code:

**file.js**

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import {View,Modal,Pressable,Text,SafeAreaView,ImageBackground,Image,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { AppButton } from '../../components/AppButton';
//import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
import '../../../translations/i18n';
import styles from './styles';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Parse from 'parse/react-native';
Parse.initialize("APP ID","JS ID"); //PASTE HERE YOUR Back4App APPLICATION ID AND YOUR JavaScript KEY
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);

  
export function HomeScreen(props){
    const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();
    
    //
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const navigateTo = val =>{
        navigation.navigate(val);
    }
    const [readResults, setReadResults] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{

        readTodos("BRjndpa3A0");
      },[]);
    const readTodos = async function (username) {
        // Reading parse objects is done by using Parse.Query
        const parseQuery = new Parse.Query('AppSettings');
        parseQuery.equalTo('objectId', username);
        try {
          let todos = await parseQuery.find();
          // Be aware that empty or invalid queries return as an empty array
          // Set results to state variable
          setReadResults(todos);
          return true;
        } catch (error) {
          // Error can be caused by lack of Internet connection
          Alert.alert('Error!', error.message);
          return false;
        }
      };
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../../assets/images/entrance2.png')} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuIcon} onPress={() => navigateTo("mainmenuscreen")}>
                    <Icon name='user-circle' style={styles.menuIconIn} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.logoAndOthers}>
                    <View style={styles.logoAndOthersIn}>
                        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                          <Image source={{uri:readResults[0] && readResults[0].get('appLogo').url()}} style={styles.logoImg} />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.selectContainer}>
                        <Pressable
                            style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOpen]}
                            
                        >
                            <View style={styles.showModalContainer}>
                              <Text style={styles.showModalDelivery}>{t("delivery")}:</Text>
                              <Text style={styles.showModalLocation}>{readResults[0] && readResults[0].get('appName')}, Israel.</Text>
                              <View style={styles.chevronIcon}>
                                <Icon name='chevron-down' />
                              </View>
                            </View>
                        </Pressable>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <AppButton title="ordernow" onPress={()=>{navigateTo("ordernowscreen")}} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
    
}
```

**i18n.js**

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';
//import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import en from './en/en.json';
import ar from './ar/ar.json';
import he from './he/he.json';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React from 'react';

const getDefaultLang = async () => {

  
  
  const storedLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentLnaguage');
  

  i18n
    .use(initReactI18next) 
    .init({
      resources: {
        en: en,
        ar: ar,
        he: he
      },
      lng: storedLang ? storedLang : 'en', 
      //lng: storedLang || "ar",
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, 
      },
      fallbackLng: ['en', 'ar','he'],
    });
    i18n.changeLanguage(storedLang);
    
};

export default getDefaultLang();
```

**UPDATE**

this is my **App.js**:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

 import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
 import  './translations/i18n';
 //import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
 import 'intl-pluralrules';
 import {AppContainer} from './Navigation';
 import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
 function App(props){
    return (
        <AppContainer isAuthenticated={false} />
    );
}
 
 export default App;
```

this is the navigation files:

**file1**:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {AuthStack} from './AuthStack';
export function AppContainer(props){
    const {isAuthenticated,} = props;
    return(
       /* <NavigationContainer>
            {isAuthenticated? <HomeTabs /> : <AuthStack />}
        </NavigationContainer>*/
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AuthStack />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

**file2**:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
import '../translations/i18n';
import { HomeScreen } from '../src/screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export function AuthStack(props){
    //const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="homescreen" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        
    );
}
```

any help please to solve this? no answers helped me yet!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible codesandbox example or similar.

Comment: I don't know how to use code sandbox because I am new to it.
can you help me in another way? maybe video chat?

Comment: @adrai I updated my question, may you check if you can help?

Comment: sorry, without any reproducible example it’s not easy to help… you can also create a small github repo

Comment: ok another question..do you know how can I Restart the app and still have the asyncstorange not null? because now, I get a null AsyncStorage if I reload